# semantic-ui-react how to use form group inside a grid

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, redux-form, semantic-ui-react

I am working on a project using semantic-ui-react. The page has a lot of inputs. I want to split the whole page into 3 columns. The following is my implementation.

```
render() {
return (
    <Form>  
        <Grid columns={3} divided>  
            <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column stretched>
                    <Segment>
                        <Form.Group widths="equal">
                            <Field name="title" component={renderFieldInput} label="Enter Title"/>
                            <Field name="test" component={renderFieldInput} label="Enter Title"/>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Segment>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column stretched>
                    <Segment>
                        test2
                    </Segment>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column stretched>
                    <Segment>
                        test3
                    </Segment>
                </Grid.Column>  
            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
    </Form>
);
```

}

The layout becomes

[image]

The Segment cannot hold the for group. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What layout are you expecting?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner. The page should have three grid columns. Each grid column should contains one form group with two equal width fields. Thanks.

Comment: And the fields are expected to layout how? Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the style guide samples: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#group-variations-evenly-divided-group

I modified the example with the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Input, Grid, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const FormExampleEvenlyDividedGroup = () => (
  <Form>
    <Grid columns={3} divided>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column stretched>
          <Segment>
            <Form.Group widths='equal'>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>First name</label>
                <Input fluid placeholder='First name' />
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Last name</label>
                <Input fluid placeholder='Last name' />
              </Form.Field>
            </Form.Group>
          </Segment>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column stretched>
          <Segment />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column stretched>
          <Segment />
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  </Form>
)

export default FormExampleEvenlyDividedGroup
```

And it appears to work. However, you are not sharing your `renderFieldInput` component, and that could be the issue:

> When using the `widths='equal'` prop declaration on a `Form.Group`, all
>   child `Form.Dropdown`, `Form.Input`, `Form.Select` components must be
>   rendered with a `fluid` prop to work correctly.

Comment: Hi Garrett, you are great. It works. I add fluid in Form.Input. Then it shows correctly.

Comment: what is meant by `fluid` BTW? I added it to `Form.CheckBox` and `From.Field` but received error.

Comment: HTML inputs are by default static width (based on the character count as hints). Specifying `fluid` makes sure that the input gets extra styling that overrides that default, letting it grow and shrink based on the relevant container size. Not all components (such as checkboxes) need that flag though. Also, see this link for some definitions: https://medium.com/@space.alpaca/so-what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-fixed-fluid-adaptive-and-responsive-layouts-and-why-3773272d8481

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `Grid.Column`'s need to live within `Grid.Row` and `Grid` components like this:

```
  <Grid columns={3} divided>
    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column>
         <Segment>
           Test1
         </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
         <Segment>
           Test2
         </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
         <Segment>
           Test3
         </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
 </Grid>
```

Similar to Twitter bootstrap grid.

See the examples here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid/#types-divided-number

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. the grid works fine when there is no form. I have updated my post. Can you help me check it? It drives me crazy with this form. Thanks.